# Is there shorthand for getting the center pixels of an image?

Tags: numpy

Is there any indexing shorthand in numpy to get the center pixels of an image (or any ND array)?

Example:

```
cutout = xc[xc.shape[0]/2-30:xc.shape[0]/2+30,xc.shape[1]/2-30:xc.shape[1]/2+30]
```

I could define a function

```
def get_center_pixels(arr, npix):
    slices = [slice(shape/2-npix,shape/2+npix) for shape in arr.shape]
    return arr[slices]

cutout = get_center_pixels(xc,30)
```

Is there a better way or a built-in way to do this?

Comment: The `get_center_pixels` function you've written for it is pretty succinct and efficient. There may be a slightly better way, but that's how I'd do it, for whatever it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

The closest standard function in numpy I can think of is [numpy.fft.fftshift](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html), which rolls the data along the selected axis, so that the center point now is at [0,0].

Comment: I had come up with that as well; it works, but isn't really any nicer than the list-of-slices approach (though, perhaps, fewer keystrokes, so +1)